# Van der Pol's equation as a system of ODE's w/ Initial Values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I need to write Van der Pol's equation with parameter $0.1$, which is
\begin{align*}
y''-(0.1)(1-y^{2})y'+y=0\qquad y(0)=1, \qquad y'(0)=0
\end{align*}
as a system of ODE's.

I write $y'=x$, and $x'=y''=(0.1)(1-y^{2})x-y$. Thus I obtain
\begin{align*}
&y'=x\\
&x'=(0.1)(1-y^{2})x-y
\end{align*}

The initial values are $x(0)=y'(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$.

Can someone check if my system and initial values are correct? Thank you.

Comment: looks correct to me ...I suppose x is not the variable..

Comment: I mean to express $y'=g(t, x, y)$ and $x'=f(t, x, y)$.

Comment: Ok Thats what i understood...Looks good to me

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct. For larger parameters than $\mu=0.1$ the numerical simulation works better, that is, allows larger step sizes, when using the fast-slow parametrization
$$
\mu v = y' - \mu(1-\tfrac13y^2)y,
$$
so that
\begin{align}
y'&=\mu[v+(1-\tfrac13y^2)y],
\\
v'&=-\frac{y}\mu.
\end{align}